# rest web service implementation Query

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-mvc

When implementing a rest webservice there are methods like `GET POST DELETE PUT`.
But if do a delete operation and i call http `GET` operation for a delete operation  whats the problem?
In the same way can i call the `POST` operation instead of `PUT` for an update operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can very well use post instead of put. All these methods exist in books, few old browsers like IE8 won't support DELETE hence most of the times you might not come across codes which use anything outside GET/POST.

Answer (score 1):

of course you can do, what you want .. 
but then it is not any more RESTfulAPI.
These methods are typically used in a RESTful API...

You can see it here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Relationship_between_URI_and_HTTP_Methods

and in detail the HTTP/1.1 Specs here:
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html